# How to force Java applet to load using TLS1.0 / TLS1.1

Tags: java, ssl, applet, java-8

I have an web application from which multiple users loads a Java applet. Now there is a problem that the loadbalancer does not support TLS1.2 which is the default for Java8 and it seems that Java8 does not automatically try lower version.

How can I force the applet to be loaded using TLS 1.0/1.1? I have tried to put this into the <applet>:

```
<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1">
```

Any help is appreciated, not very keen on solution where hundreds of users need to configure their Java clients.

This the starting point from which this question was brought up:
[Java applet not loading on Java8/HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170001/java-applet-not-loading-on-java8-https)

Comment: The client should fall back on lower versions, unless you've explicitly disabled these protocols. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to start the applet with "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1" java_argument, that did not help at least

Comment: It depends entirely on how the client code in your applet is coded (it might not even try to use `https.protocols`).

Comment: The problem is that the applet is not downloaded (JAR). At this point I think that the content of applet is not the issue. Of course if I understood wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an web application from which multiple users loads a Java applet... How can I force the applet to be loaded using TLS 1.0/1.1?

<s>The applet is loaded by the browser, not by Java. So it does not help to make any Java related settings here. These settings are only relevant if the applet itself communicates with the server.</s>
Edit: The download is done by the Java plugin. This does not affect the rest of the answer i.e. that the problem must be fixed at the load balancer.

> Now there is a problem that the loadbalancer does not support TLS1.2

Unless the load balancer is broken it will negotiate to a lower protocol version. It is inherent behavior of TLS that both parties agree to the best version both support. But, there are broken load balancers out there which simply do not understand TLS1.2 or behave strange when confronted with larger packets which are more likely with TLS1.2 (older F5, long fixed).

Unfortunately, if this happens to be such an old broken F5 you might be out of luck because a bug in these load balancers caused the packet to be dropped, so that the connection would stay open until timeout. In this case most browsers do not downgrade to a lower TLS version, because they only downgrade on immediate errors like a connection close from the peer. 
All you can do in this case is to fix the broken load balancer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. As I'm trying to verify this theory am I right that as I have selected TLS protocols 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 active from Java Advanced settings, it should work if for example only 1.0 is supported? Unless the LB is broken as you suggested.

Comment: Again, the download of the applet is done by the browser and thus is not affected by the settings for Java. These settings are relevant for network activity done by the Java applet itself. And yes, if the client can TLS 1.0..1.2 and the server can do only TLS 1.0 then the server will accept TLS 1.2 request but reply with TLS 1.0 and the rest of the connection will be done with TLS 1.0.

Comment: Wow, I'm confused... I wonder why the JAR download is successful only when I allow TLS 1.0 and disable 1.1 & 1.2 from Java settings (browser settings does not affect)... I'm quite new to Applets and I have not done it myself, maybe I need to start going through fundamentals of Java Applets once more.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the downloading of the JAR itself which is affected and not of some resources needed by the applet? The only reason I could think of is if the download itself is done by the plugin and not by the browser which would be strange indeed.

Comment: I'm beginning to be unsure ;) I'd appreciate if you could check the Java log in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170001/java-applet-not-loading-on-java8-https and see what you think of it, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are right, i.e. that the browser only calls the plugin with the parameters and the plugin then makes the requests. This does not change the fact that the load balancer is broken and the fix should be there.

Comment: Yes, apparently so. I need to contact the administration there and see if they can do anything about it. Thanks a million for the help and effort Steffen!