# How to change Java deployment.properties for Applet launch

Tags: java, ssl, applet, java-8, jnlp

Is there a way for setting Java deployment.properties before launching a Java Applet? I'm in a need for changing the "jdk.tls.client.protocols" property to only enable "TLSv1" because Java8 has enabled this by default and my Applet-JAR via HTTPS is not downloaded unless 1.1 & 1.2 protocols are disabled.

I have tried to add following options on `<APPLET>` tag with no luck:

```
1. <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1" -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1"">
2. <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1">
3. <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1"">
4. <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1">
```

Is just that the browsers do not support this kind of action or is it that Java will not allow?

Anyone has any other way of suggesting to do this?

Related questions concerning this issue:
[Java applet not loading on Java8/HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170001/java-applet-not-loading-on-java8-https) 
[How to force Java applet to load using TLS1.0 / TLS1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226448/how-to-force-java-applet-to-load-using-tls1-0-tls1-1)

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not... In my case the issue was caused by misbehavior by loadbalancer which did not negotiate the protocol correctly and by updating the LB the problem was solved.